# Activate Win10 Enterprise with Upgrade Key

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

I have a valid lot of upgrade licenses for Windows 10 Enterprise, but the activation agent won't accept it. How do I make it accept it?

I also have valid lot licenses for WinXP Pro Install and Win7 Pro Upgrade.

However, I can't install those OSs -- XP doesn't install on modern hardware, and even when it does it needs software updates before it can install Win7. Then there's the fact that it's just not reasonable to install three OSs to get to the OS I need to run.

I installed Win10 Enterprise 64bit from the "trial" ISO image on Microsoft's website (version 1703, which is the version listed on my license).

However, when I go to activate it, it rejects my Win10 key (0xC004F050). I tried entering my Win7 key to see if that would make it ask for the upgrade key or something, and it gave me another error (0xC004F210).

How do I make it accept my key?

Comment: Upgrade Windows 10 licenses don't exist.  It is not possible to activate the trial ISO image your using.  Windows 10 Enterprise has NEVER and CANNOT be activated with anything but a Windows 10 Enterprise VLK license

Comment: Windows 7 upgrade licenses cannot be used to activate Windows 10 Professional and no version of Windows XP can activate any version of Windows 10

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware that there was no distinction between upgrade/install; however, I have a valid VLK license (had to look up that term). Now that I have the disk paired with this license, will that disk be able to "upgrade" (i.e. replace, but copy over settings/drivers) the trial windows to the full windows? (Also: why on earth can't you activate it with a valid license?)

Comment: Trial installations cannot be activated on purpose.  First part of your comment makes no sense.  Can't answer a question I don't understand

Comment: How do I use the correct install media and not start from scratch? In previous systems, this was done by selecting "upgrade," even though it is the same operating system; it would simply install Windows overtop the previous Windows (even though they're the same) but it would magically work because that's how Microsoft works.

Comment: Just to confirm what I already know, Start > Settings > Update & security > Activation > Change the product key, doesn't work right?

Comment: You need to download the official Windows 10 Enterprise ISO. This is usually done through the Microsoft VLSC if you have a volume license. You can't normally convert the Enterprise trial to a full version. But, if you have created non-trial media, you can trick it into doing an "upgrade" install over top of your trial: https://winaero.com/blog/upgrade-windows-10-evaluation-to-full-version-easily/

Comment: @Ramhound - yes, that's where this thread started.

Comment: @Appleoddity - thanks; that's what I was asking at the end of the comments.

Comment: I may have solved your problem, see [my Q&A](https://superuser.com/q/1289515/77053) on this subject